# Polynomial Inversion over Galois Field

Tags: cryptanalysis, elliptic-curves, modular-arithmetic

Hello guys I am looking to calculate the Inverse of a given polynomial in Galois field
I have found the little Fermat's algorithm and the Itoh-Tsujii 
I am getting a bit confused with both algorithm as
if having a squaring and multiplication operation
should a reduction modulus be used [A.A mod F(x)] and then A.[A.A mod F(x)] and so on
or the modulus operation should be used at the end of the final answer [A.A.A.A....]mod F(x)

Are they applicable to polynomials basis and not normal basis ?
or is this operation for the GF(2) and not the extended fields ?

Thank you

Comment: The question seems to be whether you calculate $a^n\bmod f$ by first multiplying $a$ with itself $n$ times and *then* reducing the result modulo $f$ **or** multiplying $a$ with itself *modulo* $f$ (i.e. reducing after *each* multiplication) $n$ times. Did I get this right?

Comment: Yes, Can I do that ? distribute the modulus on each operation ? since squaring a polynomial that number of times is a bit huge for a hardware implementation

Comment: Yes, you can: both options are mathematically valid since reduction modulo $f$ is a homomorphism.

Comment: Inversion (in any field) can be done with Extended Euclidean algorithm; algorithm input is field element in question and generating polynomial.